# Are there any differentiable points on the boundary of the Mandelbrot set?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

I'm wondering if there are any points in the Mandelbrot set that are continuous or differentiable?  Precisely, is there some point $x_0$ in the set such that there is a continuous/differentiable/smooth function $\varphi: [0,1] \rightarrow M$ such that $\varphi([0,1]) \in M$?  I'm not sure I'm phrasing this correctly, but geometrically, if we "zoom in" enough around some point in the Mandelbrot set, do we see the image of a continuous/differentiable/smooth function?  Please let me know if this is unclear.

Comment: There are certainly many smooth curves contained in the boundary of the Mandelbrot set, including the main cardioid and a circle as I described in my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109402/). But any open disk intersecting any one of those curves is certain to contain other points in the boundary as well.